# how to enable full width page template in woo theme memorable?

Tags: widgets

I have been trying to remove sidebar so i can use full width of page but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea how to enable full width page template in woo theme memorable?

Comment: did you also change the width ofd main div(center div ) to fit the page besides removing sidebar ??

Comment: wordpresser thank you for replying...id love to do  what you suggest...but am such a noob i dont know how?...can you please elaborate on where id find the place to do that..?

Comment: post your template page code you want to make full width or if your site is live you may share link

Answer (score 0):

on http://www.southalgonquincottages.com/wp-content/themes/memorable/css/layout.css (line 480)

```
change
 #main {
    width: 74%;
}
```

to

```
 #main {
    width: auto;
}
```

on http://www.southalgonquincottages.com/wp-content/themes/memorable/css/layout.css (line 473)

```
#main.fullwidth, .layout-full #main, .col-full {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1140px; <-- REMOVE THIS CODE SNIPPET
    width: 100%;
}
```

it should be

```
#main.fullwidth, .layout-full #main, .col-full {
    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: wordpresser you have been too kind and patient with me...i must be really dumb but as i cant edit from the links you sent me,  how do i get to that page of code in my admin panel??

Comment: i did find the line of code but couldnt delete or add to it on the link you sent and am unable to find exactly where that code is in my admin panel...

Comment: dude thats in your styesheet, if you dont know that i would advice you to learn basics first . you have to open taht file in your editor ..:D

Comment: thanks again for your patience... its my first wordpress build...you have been more than kind :-)

Comment: i had to attend to other issue for a while...but again thanks to wordpresser!!... just did it... thanks to your help